# Realm Authentication Server Error with iCloud Auth

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

*RealmSwift 2.8.3, Realm Object Server 1.8.1, Xcode 8, Swift 3.1*

I can get pretty much everything with the Realm Object Server (ROS) to work with iCloud authentication, but I'm running into an issue when I have a new user authenticate that doesn't yet have an account on my ROS instance.

I'm successfully able to retrieve their iCloud token, but `user` is `nil` when I do this:

```
let credentials = SyncCredentials.cloudKit(token: token)

SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: serverURL) { user, error in
  DispatchQueue.main.async{
    if user == nil {
      //--- Error ---
      //This is where I end up. I can see the token in the log but no user object
    }else{
      //--- Success ---
    }
  } 
}
```

When I check the error log in my ROS (running on Ubuntu), I get this internal server error (500):

```
2017-07-12T00:39:39.170Z - warn: auth.cloudkit: Handle request failed with: Error: Request failed with code AUTHENTICATION_FAILED: Authentication failed.

2017-07-12T00:39:39.174Z - warn: [services] internal error: Error: Request failed with code AUTHENTICATION_FAILED: Authentication failed.
at request.catch.err (/usr/lib/nodejs/realm-object-server-developer/.build/src/node/managers/auth/provider/cloudkit.js:131:23)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7).
```

Now just to make sure, I assume that `SyncCredentials.cloudKit(token: token)` **creates a user** if that token isn't found on my server and returns a new user object. I don't see anything in the docs about creating a new user vs. authenticating an existing one.

**UPDATE**

I double-checked all my connections to iCloud, made sure my `key_id` found in my `configuration.yml` file is right and that my key matches what I have in my iCloud container.

Now I get a different error. :)

```
2017-07-12T01:12:54.801Z - warn: auth.cloudkit: Handle request failed with: TypeError: Cannot read property 'reason' of undefined

2017-07-12T01:12:54.809Z - warn: [services] internal error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'reason' of undefined
at signedRequest.then.catch.err (/usr/lib/nodejs/realm-object-server-developer/.build/src/node/managers/auth/provider/cloudkit.js:86:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7).
```

Comment: If you're seeing `internal error`s in the Realm Object Server, I suggest you file a bug report along with detailed steps to reproduce here: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/new

Comment: @jpsim I filed one, but already closed it since I found the (unrelated) solution. Feel free to reopen and pursue a more clear error message: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/237

Comment: how are you getting icloud token ?

Comment: @AdamSmaka Like this: http://d.pr/n/O8rdQx+

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#access-control), account should be created if not existed before

> If the credentials are valid, the user is granted access to Realm
>   Object Server. A new user account is created if the credentials are
>   not coupled to an existing account.

I guess it's problem with private_key_path in configuration.yml. Try to move .pem file to another location and see if there are any changes.

Also, remember to restart the server after changing the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I found the solution as noted here: https://www.twelvesouth.com/wallpaper/collection5 The problem was related to an incorrect iCloud key ID.